# How to go around the lack of generics in this simple case

Tags: go

I am creating a simple `sql` mapper that allows me to create sql mappings at run time because i have no idea how the database schema will be like.

consider the following struct:

```
type SqlColumn struct {
    name string
    columnType ? //int float etc...
}
```

what type should i use for the `columnType` field?

the only way i could think of is to use strings or a const and handle the rest using reflection, am i on the right path?

Comment: Random note, this kind of thing is not needed 99% of the time and it's just an overkill, also keep in mind your `name` and `columnType` are not exported, so they won't be usable outside your package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `interface{}` for this:

```
type SqlColumn struct {
    name string
    columnType interface{}
}
```

Comment: but the problem is if i use reflect.Kind on that field what would i get?

Comment: You will get the proper type for it, `reflect.Int`, etc.